# Created android platform with cordova but got nothing

Tags: android, cordova

When I created a Cordova project , I used

```
E:\test\hello>cordova platform add android
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-4.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-4.0.0.tgz
E:\test\hello>
```

to support Android platforms, but there's nothing under platform directory while I expected Android directory to be created, how can I solve this?

Comment: Is that your full command? You have to run cordova create test com.example.com test after that, cd test, and then cordova platform add android

Comment: I've already created the cordova project by cordova create hello com.example.com and then got into hello directory